# What is the difference between the URL "file://" and "http://"

Tags: url

I was asked this question in one of my assignments. I was wondering what the difference is in the URLs of the attached image. I know it has something to do with the "file://" and "http://" but I'm not sure how to explain or phrase it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to understand about the `file` and `http`. Both are protocols and serves two different purpose.
for your reference:

[fileProtocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767731(v%3Dvs.85))

[HTTPProtocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767734(v%3Dvs.85))

Answer (score 2):

`file://` is a request for a local file. `http://` is using HTTP protocol to request a file somewhere, including -- if it's the case -- on your local computer.

Answer (score 1):

They have different schemes. One says look on the file system, the other says make a HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

A file requested via `file://` gets opened from local drive. A file requested via `http://` gets via HTTP request to URL that comes after it. The second might come from your own computer (example `http://localhost ...`) or from anywhere on the web. Although the image might be the same as in your example, it is served via two different protocols.